# I want to store Matcher variable as a string

Tags: java, regex

I want my application to read any match as string.

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Problem 1: Create a heading using h1 tag");
    String input = reader.nextLine();
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<[a-z][0-9]>");
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);
    if(m.find()){
        String meme = m.group(0);
        System.out.println(meme);
        if(meme == "<h1>"){
            System.out.println("Found a string.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No string found.");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No closing tag.");
    }
```

For example I 
input `<..h1..>` (disregard dots)
but the output is always `No string found` even though I set meme `== <..h1..>` . How can i convert it to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is in this line

```
 if(meme == "<h1>")
```

It should be

```
if(meme.equals("<h1>"))
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `(meme == "<h1>")`.

Because the equality operator (`==`) compares based on reference and not value, this is actually comparing two separate strings: `meme` and `"<h1>"`.  Instead, use:

```
    if(meme.equals("<h1>")){
```

Comment: Thanks for helping though! If only I could accept 2 answer

Comment: No problem! :-D